# Как получить url страницы редиректа используя с# selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Есть сайт (это URL №1), например http://my.site.com При регистрации идет перенаправление на промежуточную страницу редирект (это URL №2) на 1 секунду и потом идет следующее перенаправление на заключительную страницу регистрации (это URL №3).

Вопрос: как получить URL страницы редиректа (string RedirPage; это URL №2), которая появляется на 1 секунду?

Мой код:

```
string FirstPage = http://my.site.com;

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(FirstPage);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtFirstName")).SendKeys("Иван");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtEmail")).SendKeys("i@i.ua");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSubmit")).Click();
string RedirPage;


do

{

RedirPage = driver.Url;

}
while (LP[i] == F);
```

Comment: **При использовании данного кода я получаю заключительную страницу регистрации (это URL №3).**

Comment: нет
Я заполняю поля формы регистрации "Имя" и "E-mail" которая есть на сайте  http://my.site.com
я хочу получить URL страницы которая загружается после URL сайта http://my.site.com  когда была нажата кнопка Submit и были отправлены данные формы регистрации.
В моем случае идет поочередная смена страниц: №1 -> №2 -> №3
**Мне нужно получить URL страницы №2**

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял суть, то так:

```
...
RedirPage = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("form")).GetAttribute("action");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSubmit")).Click();
```

Comment: нет.   Мне не нужно искать элемент на странице.  Мне нужен URL

Comment: вы заходите на страницу №1 там есть форма, которая при сабмите отправляет данные на №2, после обработки формы вы попадаете на финальную страницу №3 так? Куда же по вашему вас отправляет форма со страницы №1, логично предположить что на №2? В этом случае в чем проблема взять URL из разметки из атрибута `action` у тега `form`?

Comment: я не могу с помощью вашего кода получить URL страницы №2
т.к. мне нужно получить динамически загружаемый URL с уникальными параметрами с ответом от сервера. Поэтому, если у вас есть другой вариант, буду очень благодарен за помощь